# Wordpress: Display categories in two drop down and display the posts that is common for the categories selected in both dropdowns

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I have created two categories say city and manufacturer.

and I have added city names as subcategory to city and manufacturer names as sub-category of manufacturer.

```
Example:
  city
   - newyork
   - paris
 Manufacturer
   - BMW
   - Audi
```

Now I need to display City list in one dropdown and manufacturer in another dropdown.

Now After selecting city and manufacturer details and clicking on search it should display posts which are part of both city and manufacturer categories.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this which will solve your problem.

```
<form method="get" action="" id="findresult">
    <h2><?php _e( 'City' ); ?></h2>       
   <?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select City&name=city&child_of=43'); //43 is id of city category ?>
   <h2><?php _e( 'Manufacturer' ); ?></h2>
   <?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select Manufacturer&name=manufacturer&child_of=44'); //44 is id of manufacturer category ?>
   <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>

<?php 
if (($_GET['city'] != -1) && ($_GET['manufacturer'] != -1)):

    $query = new WP_Query(array('category__and' => array($_GET['city'],$_GET['manufacturer'])));
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        echo "<p>".the_title()."</p>";
        echo "<p>".the_content()."</p>";
    endwhile;endif;

endif;
?>
```